# How does the javascript kleene star interact with grouping?

Tags: javascript, regex

This seems really simple, maybe I'm missing something obvious. I'd like to return all of a variable length substring in a string with the pattern `(.*)`. I find I'm getting very strange behavior in the Firefox console though:

```
"666677888".match(/.*(7{1}).*/)[1];
> "7"
"666677888".match(/.*(7{2}).*/)[1];
> "77"
```

So far so good. Then:

```
"666677888".match(/.*(7*).*/)[1];
> ""
"666677888".match(/.*(7{0,2}).*/)[1];
> ""
"666677888".match(/.*(7{0,}).*/)[1];
> ""
```

This seems to indicate that 7 matches `{1}` time, and `{2}` times, but not `{0,}` times or `{0,2}` times. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think that since your pattern is OK with matching zero occurrences of "7", the `.*` eats the whole thing. It's more efficient to exclude things you don't want in situations like this with something like `/[^7]*(7*).*/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the regular expression is greedy, so it will backtrack to find a match for the second part.

For the pattern `.*(7{1}).*` the first `.*` will start by matching the entire string, then it has to shrink that by a character at a time until it can find the second `7` to match `7{1}`.

For the pattern `.*(7{0,2}).*` the first `.*` will match the entire string, and then it doesn't have to do anything more, because both `7{0,2}` and the second `.*` are fulfilled with empty strings at the end of the string.

To make the expression match `7{0,2}` you have to force it to match all the `7` there are by matching something after it, for example a character that's not `7`, and also force that to match something, for example by including the end of the string. The pattern `.*?(7{0,2})[^7]*$` will match the `77`.

Comment: No, `.*?` won't fix the problem. I thought it would too! I *think* it's because the pattern is satisfied once the entire string is consumed by `.*`; the pattern allows for zero "7" characters to be matched ...

Comment: @Pointy - you are right.  `/(.*)(7{0,})(.*)/` would match `"117722"` as `(117722)()()`. [`/(.*?)(7{0,})(.*)/`](http://rubular.com/r/MAEQUWuBBX) would match it as `()()(117722)`. Either way `7*` does not capture anything interesting. If you allow zero length, you should be prepared for zero sevens...